# How to install the Nokogiri gem using Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 with my Rails v3.2.19 application and I'm unable to run bundle because Nokogiri requires a Ruby version >= 2.1.0. At the moment I cannot upgrade my Ruby version and I really need to install Nokogiri otherwise my app won't run.

Besides the regular solutions using `gem install`, I've already tried the following command line with no success:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2

ERROR: 
>Error installing nokogiri:
nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
```

Is there a way that I can install Nokogiri using my current Ruby version?

Additional Info:

- Rails version - 3.2.19
- Ruby version - 1.9.3
- Nokogiri version - 1.7.0.1
- OS - CentOS 7

Comment: Make sure Ruby is using the right $PATH for rbenv or rvm, not the system ruby path. `which ruby` should give /Users/{user}/.rbenv/shims/ruby

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 is extremely out of date, and isn't recommended, so getting it upgraded is important. Have you investigated using RVM or rbenv to allow you to install and manage Ruby in your home directory? Then you are freely able to upgrade it or run multiple versions.

Comment: You're right, maybe it's really better to upgrade my ruby version as soon as possible.  I'm already using RVM but I just want to make sure that there are no compatibility issues with my app first. 

However, I've done a workaround to fix my problem. In the Gemfile I've set the Nokogiri to a previous version, one works with ruby 1.9.3, and my app started to work again. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

The last version of `nokogiri` to support Ruby 1.9.3 was 1.6.8.1, so you need to do something like

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

First try update xcode command line tools `xcode-select --install`

Then try these steps https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/What-to-do-if-libxml2-is-being-a-jerk

Comment: I've decided to set Nokogiri to a previous version for now and to upgrade my ruby version as soon as possible. Sooner or later I'll face the same issue with other gems... But thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: Be careful before running this command. After running this command, my system (Mac OS Catalina) updated some package to newer version, and it not compatible with current library version (Example: icu4c is being update from 64.2 to 67.1, then postgres cannot start, php5.6 cannot start + apache re installed). I only want to install nokogiri but some of other library is updated, and it not necessary at all. I'm stuck and I'm thinking about reset my computer and start over again T.T